# OpenGL - Passing a vector into glDrawElements()

Tags: opengl, vector

I'm trying to pass a vector into the last argument of glDrawElements(). If I used array, it worked fine. However, when I switched to a vector, it only rendered a portion of the object.

This worked just fine:

```
//TA_CartesianSys.h
class TA_CartesianSys
{
    private:
        int drawOrder[86];
    //the rest of the class
}


//---------------------------------
//TA_CartesianSys.cpp
TA_CartesianSys::TA_CartesianSys()
{
    GLfloat CartesianVertices[] = { ... };
    int tempOrder[] = { ... };
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(tempOrder) / sizeof(int); i++)
    {
         drawOrder[i] = tempOrder[i];
    }
    //Code to generate and bind vertex array and buffer
    glDrawElements(GL_LINES, sizeof(drawOrder)/sizeof(int), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, drawOrder);
}
```

It worked as expected, and this was how it looked like:

[image]

Now, I decided to use vector instead of array for drawOrder[]. This is the new code:

```
//TA_CartesianSys.h
class TA_CartesianSys
{
    private:
    std::vector<int> drawOrder; //***NOTE: This is the change   
    //the rest of the class
}
//---------------------------------
//TA_CartesianSys.cpp
TA_CartesianSys::TA_CartesianSys()
{
    GLfloat CartesianVertices[] = { ... };
    int tempOrder[] = { ... };

    drawOrder.resize(sizeof(tempOrder) / sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(tempOrder) / sizeof(int)); i++)
    {
        drawOrder[i] = tempOrder[i];
    }

    //Code to generate and bind vertex array and buffer - Same as above

    glDrawElements(GL_LINES, sizeof(drawOrder)/sizeof(int), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &drawOrder[0]);
}
```

And this was what I got when I ran the program:

[image]

NOTE: the square in the middle was not part of this object. It belonged to a totally different class.

So, basically, when I changed the drawOrder[] to vector instead of array, only a small part of my object was rendered (the 2 lines). The rest were no seen.

I put a break point right at the draw() function, and it showed that the drawOrder vector was initialized properly, with the exact same value as its array counter part.

[image]

So, why am I only getting 2 lines instead of the whole grids? What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sizeof` on a vector object just tells you the size of the vector class instance, not the number of elements. What you want is the size member fucction of std::vector, which tells you the number of elements (i.e. you must not divide the number returned by std::vector::size by the element sizeof).

```
glDrawElements(
    GL_LINES,
    drawOrder.size(), // <<<<<
    GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
    &drawOrder[0] );
```

Comment: Yeah, I realized that just now. I should have looked more carefully. Thank you for the response.